# Can't get interactive matplotlib plotting working (when NOT in Jupyter mode)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've spent several hours trying to figure out how to get interactive plots to work on MacOS Catalina (plots which don't block program execution in debug mode). I'm NOT operating in Juptyer notebook mode. As cool as Jupyter notebooks are, that's not what I'm after. I'm after a user experience with plots that is akin to working with plots in Matlab.

I got fairly excited when I found instructions in the Matplotlib docs for using python as a framework and then using the macosx backend, but it doesn't seem to help. I'm operating in debug mode from Visual Studio Code, which otherwise seems to work well. Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np 

matplotlib.use("macosx") 
plt.ion() 
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)  # Create a list of evenly-spaced numbers over the range 
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))       # Plot the sine of each x point 
plt.show() 
# put a breakpoint on this next line 
y = 5
```

If I omit the call to plt.ion(), I get a plot that blocks program execution until I close the plot window, so I don't hit the breakpoint until the plot is gone. If I leave the call to plot.ion() in, I hit the breakpoint, but no plot is shown. Oddly, in this case, there then seems to be an extra python process in the dock, as I'm used to seeing in Spyder when doing the same sort of thing (but in Spyder, I can actually see a plot).

Does anyone know if is possible to get this to work, and if so, how? I've got this sort of thing to work before with Spyder, but it is hinky, and I've got other issues with Spyder.